# connecting table data and form text fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html/css page that is supposed to use an html table layout full of buttons to simulate a t9 keypad layout.

On the page I have a form that includes two text fields. I want to use the table/keypad values to fill in the text fields with numbers via javascript.

I was able to associate a variable with a string that describes which field I wish to fill in with the data, but when I call for the current value of the field I get an error (console.log) that says "cannot read property 'x' of 'undefined'.

Here is my function.

```
function place(id) {
        var key = ""; //Ensure that this is a string, not number
        key = document.getElementById(id).id; //Get the key value.
        console.log(key);
        var total = ""; //initialize variable.
        console.log(appSettings.padName);
        total = nums.element[appSettings.padName].value; //Grab total.
        //if (total.contains("Click")) total = "";
        console.log(total);
        if (key == "-1") total.slice(0, -1); //backspace.
        else if (key == "-2") numPad(appSettings.padName); //Enter.
        else total += key; //concat to end of the String.
        document.getElementById(appSettings.padName).value += total; //place update.
    }
```

I am calling this function with the following html

```
<div id="nums">
<form name="nums">
    <h3>
    Cell number: <input type="text" id="cell" value="" class="inputText"      size="10" onclick="numPad('cell')" name="cell" /><br/><br/>
    <div id='group'>
    Party size: <input type="text" value="" class="inputText" size="10" onclick="numPad('group')" name="group" /><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</h3>
```

*note that each field has a different ID system.

The function that gathers the variable is working correctly gathering the div ID in a string format (aka 'cell'). If you need more information to help I am happy to supply :P

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Also, where is appSettings and nums defined?  Actually, now that I think about it, is this a .net app?

Comment: its just an html page. I have appSettings defined as a global in another function. the 'nums' refers to the form; its the ID (second code snippet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go about this from a different approach, entirely. The best solution would be to listen for a `click` event on the `<table>`, and from there you can grab which key has been clicked, and update one of the inputs accordingly. This practice is called *Event Delegation*, and it is very efficient.

There are a few faults with your current javascript. Firstly, you don't need to initialize variables and assign them a "type", before assigning them your intended values. As well, you don't need to look up an element by it's ID simply to grab the ID again, this is wasteful. I notice that you're also referring to a number of global variables in your function, this is generally bad practice.

Another note, the information that Chris Lively provided you with, re: semi-colons is blatantly false. There are no issues with your original if-statements. You can learn more from this post: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: That does sound a lot better. I will be working that out then. I have 1 global variable here, but I am not certain how I can get rid of it as it tells which field the information is going to update.

Comment: @Andy It looks like `nums` is also global. Also, FWIW, libraries like jQuery and Dojo have things like *Event Delegation* built in, and make it very convenient to use.

Comment: thanks, looked that up and it does look like exactly what I did not know I needed. much appreciated. nums is the form ID, not a variable.

Comment: @Andy This is a simple version of how you might accomplish your goal in an efficient manner: http://jsfiddle.net/Vuvgd/

Comment: @gf3: A little research and I learn something; thanks.  I would still change to using curly braces instead of those semi-colons but that's apparently a matter of opinion. ;)

Comment: @Chris Lively, indeed, it pays to know the rules of ASI, as then you're really free to write code in whatever manner you prefer.